# Linq Multiple Joins to SelectList

Tags: linq, join

The Below Linq query returns my values from S.

```cs
List<SelectListItem> sNos = _ctx.S.AsNoTracking()                    
                            .Select(n =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = n.SID.ToString(),
                    Text = n.SNO
                }).ToList();

return new SelectList(sNos, "Value", "Text");
```

I now need to further refine my linq query by applying a join for example my entity "b" has an id to join to so i've tried something like this, but with now luck. Can someone show my syntactically how to apply the join correctly in linq?

```cs
List<SelectListItem> sNos = _ctx.S.AsNoTracking()  
                    join b in _ctx.B 
                    on b.BID = s.SID                  
                            .Select(n =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = n.SID.ToString(),
                    Text = n.SNO
                }).ToList();

return new SelectList(sNos, "Value", "Text");
```

Both entities have been mapped in my DBContext page.

Comment: I see mix of Method Chain and Query Comprehension syntax. Choose something one. And there a lot of answers how to join two tables via LINQ.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv can you please elaborate I am very new to linq query.

Comment: @AndyWilliams was saying there are 2 LINQ syntaxes, [method syntax](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-method-syntax) and [query syntax](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-query-syntax). Please select one or the other consistently when you update your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of joins, I prefer Query Syntax:

```cs
var query =
    from s in _ctx.S
    join b in _ctx.B on b.BID equals s.SID
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = s.SID.ToString(),
        Text = s.SNO,
        BValue = b.SomeField
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Details on join clauses can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause).